# Eclipse says "package is not accesible", despite adding it to the classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, classpath, buildpath

I'm stuck on trying to import an external library into an existing Eclipse project. I've followed the steps in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rzB0s_76dBg) (hopefully not outdated), but I'm still getting error messages saying I need to re-create those classes within the src folder. I've attached 2 photos, hopefully they provide some insight:
[View of errors within a class + project hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtPw5.png) and
[Project Build Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nx8ir.png)

Comment: You have a `module-info.java`. Are you trying to use the Java module system?

Comment: Yeah I get a prompt to "add 'require courserajava' to module-info.java" when I hover over the classes from the external library, but adding that line in module-info.java doesn't fix the issue.